# LinkSys wireless router failing DHCP

Tags: dhcp

I have a home network that has an ActionTec Router/DSL Modem plugged into the phone line, with my desktop computer plugged into it.

I also have a LinkSys WRT54G2 Wireless-G broadband router plugged into it, to which I connect laptops, Ebook readers, etc.

The WRT54G2 is configured to run as a DHCP server.  The ActionTec is serving addresses in 192.168.0.*, the LinkSys is serving addresses in 192.168.1.*.

Things work fine, for a while.  Laptops can connect to the internet, without a problem.  For a while.

After what can be a few weeks or a few hours, laptops fail to connect.  Or rather, they seem to connect to the LinkSys, pass authentication, and then fail to obtain an IP address.  It looks like the LinkSys' DHCP server is failing to issue new addresses.

A power cycle of the LinkSys fixes everything, for a while.  But a few days later, and the problem will be back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution here is to turn off DHCP on one of the devices. 2 DHCP servers on a single network will only ever cause problems.

Comment: They're not on the same network.  They're on different subnets.

Comment: Why not have everything on the same subnet?

Comment: Because that means figuring out how to configure the LinkSys to work in bridged mode.  I tried that, and couldn't get it to work.  Meanwhile, the wireless devices don't need access to the devices on the wired network, they just need to be able to access the internet, and the current configuration works, until the LinkSys DHCP locks up.

Comment: Is there a newer firmware for your Linksys?

Answer (score 0):

In the past I've reflashed my Linksys device to resolve issues such as these.  You may also consider something like [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index), which would allow you to use the device as an access point in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a firmware issue. Check for upgrade it.

http://www.linksysbycisco.com/UK/en/support/WRT54G2